# React using context, and useRef returning null when trying to test login

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

So, I'm using useContext along with useRef to store user information for a mern blog app. When i click the login button the console is logging null instead of the user credentials

Login file:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useContext, useRef } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Context } from "../../context/Contex";
import "./login.css";

export default function Login() {
  const userRef = useRef();
  const passwordRef = useRef();
  const {user, dispatch, isFetching } = useContext(Context);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_START" });
    try {
      const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login", {
        username: userRef.current.value,
        password: passwordRef.current.value,
      });
      dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", payload: res.data });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_FAILURE" });
    }
  };

  console.log(user)

  return (
    <div className="login">
      <span className="loginTitle">Login</span>
      <form className="loginForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>Username</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="loginInput"
          placeholder="Enter your username..."
          ref={userRef}
        />
        <label>Password</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          className="loginInput"
          placeholder="Enter your password..."
          ref={passwordRef}
        />
        <button className="loginButton" type="submit" disabled={isFetching}>
          Login
        </button>
      </form>
      <button className="loginRegisterButton">
        <Link className="link" to="/register">
          Register
        </Link>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is my Context file:

```
import {createContext, useReducer} from "react"
import Reducer from "./Reducer"

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    user: null,
    isFetching: false,
    error: false
}

export const Context = createContext(INITIAL_STATE)

export const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state,dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, INITIAL_STATE)
    return (
        <Context.Provider value={{
        user: state.user, 
        isFetching: state.isFetching, 
        error: state.error,
        dispatch,
        }}>
            {children}
        </Context.Provider>
    )
}
```

And finally my Reducer:

```
const Reducer = (state, action)=>{
    switch(action.type) {
       case "LOGIN_START":
        return {
            user: null,
            isFetching: true,
            error: false
        }
        case "LOGOUT_SUCCESS":
            return {
                user: action.payload,
                isFetching: false,
                error: false,
        }
        case "LOGOUT_FAILURE":
            return {
                user: null,
                isFetching: false,
                error: true,
        }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default Reducer
```

Let me also add my Actions file for reference:

```
export  const LoginStart = (userCredentials)=>(
    {
        type: "LOGIN_START"
    }
)

export const LoginSuccess = (user)=>({
    type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS",
    payload: user,
})

export const LoginFailure = ()=>({
    type: "LOGIN_FAILURE"
})
```

What do i seem to be doing wrong here, FYI i know there's a typo in the name of the context file 'contex' this is fine and noted, I realised after the fact i forgot the T and just ran with it since it imported everywhere it needed to fine.

Comment: Your reducer doesn't support any `LOGIN_SUCCESS` action type. It's also unclear what your _"Actions file"_ has to do with any of this

Comment: Ah, im so dumb. I didn't catch that (had been working on this for 4 hours)